# Why doesn't TypeScript produce an error for this mapped type?

Tags: typescript

```
type JsonType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, "salt" | "hash">]: string;
};

type Test = {
  salt: string;
  hash: string;
};

const testObject: JsonType<Test> = {
  hash: "...",
  salt: "...",
};
```

why I'm not getting any error for defining an object named `testObject` of type `JsonType<Test>`?  I excluded "salt" and "hash" from the type but I still can use them in an object when I expect them to be invalid.

I tried the code below but nothing has changed:

```
type JsonType<T> = {
  [P in Exclude<keyof T, "salt" | "hash">]: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `JsonType<Test>` will result in `Record<never, string>`, which is basically an object with no keys:

```
// never
type Keys = Exclude<keyof Test, 'salt' | 'hash'>
```

Since there is no strict type checking in the Typescript, in this case it allows you to assign additional properties to this variable without raising a type error, which is a design choice to avoid complex type dealing in other cases.